# No me funciona Header:Location en MVC cuando lo subo al servidor web

Tags: php, mvc, servidor, headers

Buen dia

Necesito su ayuda llevo muchos dias con el problema y no logro entender la causa, ya he aplicado miles de opciones que veo en internet pero nada funciona.

lo que pasa es que cuando intento usar el botón de editar el realiza los cambios pero no me redirecciona a la pagina donde visualizo todos los cambios, esto solo me sucede cuando subo el proyecto a mysitearea.com, pero en mi servidor local funciona a la perfección

aquí les dejo todo el código y el lugar donde lo estoy subiendo es mysitearea.com

**Pagina donde se reciben los datos::..**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card text-center m-3">
            <!--Titulo-->
            <div class="card-herader bg-info">
                <h1>Editar Seccion</h1>
            </div>
            <!--Formulario-->
            <div class="card-body">
                <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $sect->id_seccion ?>">

                    <div class="mb-3 row">
                        <label for="seccion" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Seccion</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtSeccion" id="seccion" value="<?php echo $sect->seccion ?>">
                        </div>                           
                        <label for="imagen" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Imagen</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <input type="hidden" name="txtImgAnt" value="<?php echo $sect->imagen ?>">
                            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="txtImage" id="imagen" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png">
                        </div>
                        <label for="seccion" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Estado</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <select name="txtEstado" id="" class="form-control text-center">
                                        <option value="0" <?php if($sect->estado==0){ echo "selected";} ?>> Inactivo</option>
                                        <option value="1" <?php if($sect->estado==1){ echo "selected";} ?>> Activo</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <!--Botones-->
            <div class="card-footer">
                <div class="row text-right">
                    <div class="col-9"></div>
                    <div class="col-3">
                        <a href="?controller=secciones&action=show" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg"><span class="fa-solid fa-rectangle-list"></span> Lista Secciones</a>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg m-auto" name="save"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check"></i> Editar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Aqui recibe los datos el controllador y debería de redirigir**
Vale la aclaración que el si realiza el proceso de actualizar los datos mas no me reenvía a la pagina SHOW que es donde los visualizo.

```
    public function edit(){

    if($_POST){

        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $seccion = $_POST['txtSeccion'];

        if($_FILES['txtImage']['size']>0){

            $folderSection = "./views/secciones/img/".$seccion;
            if(!file_exists($folderSection)){
                mkdir($folderSection, 0777, true);
            }

            $imagen = $_FILES['txtImage']['name'];
            $imgTmp = $_FILES['txtImage']['tmp_name'];
            $imgUrl = $folderSection."/".$imagen;
            copy($imgTmp, $imgUrl);
        }else{
            $imagen = $_POST['txtImgAnt'];
        }

        $estado = $_POST['txtEstado'];
        $usuario = '1';
        Seccion::editSection($id,$seccion,$imagen,$usuario,$estado);
        header("Location:./?controller=secciones&action=show"); //esto no me carga en mysitearea, pero si es desde mi servidor local si
        
    }

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sect = Seccion::searchSection($id);

    include_once("views/secciones/edit.php");
}
```

**No veo necesario dejarles el modelo, porque como dije antes el si realiza los cambios mas no me envia a la pagina de visualizacion**

voy ha dejar el codigo de index y root por si les es util.

**index**

```
include_once("controllers/".ucfirst($controller)."Controller.php");

$objController = $controller."Controller";
$controller = new $objController();
$controller->$action();
```

**ROOT**

```
include_once("controllers/".ucfirst($controller)."Controller.php");

$objController = $controller."Controller";
$controller = new $objController();
$controller->$action();
```

Agradecería mucho cualquier ayuda o consejo que me puedan dar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿A dónde te manda pues?

Comment: Puedes agregar la estructura de folders que tienes?

Comment: Le función `header()` solo envía un encabezado al navegador y hay dos cosas importantes: 1) Necesitas agregar `exit; ` para finalizar la ejecución del script 2) No debes haber enviado contenido (espacios, saltos de línea, texto, HTML, etc) previamente

Comment: @A.Cedano solo carga los cambios pero no me cambia de pagina, me debería después de hacer un cambio o crear un nuevo dato de enviar a la tabla de visualización.

Comment: @Sr1871 claro ya la monto